# Fatal error: Call to a member function user() on boolean

Tags: cakephp, fatal-error, cakephp-3.3

I have to use **loggedIn** user data in **view** therefore creating a variable **AUTH_USER** in `AppController` in `beforeRender` function.

```
82     public function beforeRender(Event $event)
83     {
84          if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
85          $this->set('AUTH_USER', $this->Auth->user());
86          }
87          ...
88          ...
89     }
```

Whenever there is an error, instead of displaying actual error it shows following error without style formatting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function user() on boolean in /path_to_app/src/Controller/AppController.php:84 
Stack trace: #0 /path_to_app/src/Controller/ErrorController.php(54): App\Controller\AppController->beforeRender(Object(Cake\Event\Event)) 
#1 /path_to_app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(422): App\Controller\ErrorController->beforeRender(Object(Cake\Event\Event)) 
#2 /path_to_app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(391): Cake\Event\EventManager->_callListener(Array, Object(Cake\Event\Event)) 
#3 /path_to_app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php(78): Cake\Event\EventManager->dispatch(Object(Cake\Event\Event)) 
#4 /path_to_app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ in /path_to_app/src/Controller/AppController.php on line 84
```

Removing line `84 - 86` displays actual error

> Edit 2

**code for Auth component load in AppController initialize()**

I have written the following code to load the `AUTH` component.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
   'authenticate' => [
      'Form' => [
         'userModel' => 'Admins',
            'fields' => [
               'username' => 'email', 
               'password' => 'password'
             ]
         ]
      ],
      'loginAction' => [
         'controller' => 'Admins',
         'action' => 'index'
      ],
      'loginRedirect' => [
         'controller' => 'Admins',
         'action' => 'contentList'
       ],
      'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
      'logoutAction' => [
         'controller' => 'Pages',
         'action' => 'home'
       ]
]);
```

Comment: You are missing an `]` when loading the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same error and if you add this line to `beforeRender()` it should work:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth');
```

It could be that you are not properly initializing the component in the `initialize()` function.

Comment: If user's data is already there in `Auth` session. Why to fetch again from database ? This could be vulnerable as on fetching user's record, password and other hidden data will be retrieved too. Also, since the code is in `AppController`, loggedIn user data will be retrieved with every http request sent to the server.

Comment: Error is there even after I changed my code accordingly as per your answer. error is on line `if (!empty($this->Auth->user('id')))`.

Comment: Are you loading the "Auth" component in the initialize() function?

Comment: I have edited my question. You can see the code I have written to load the AUTH component

Comment: What happens if you add `$this->loadComponent('Auth');` to line 84, just before the if-statement?

Comment: Nothing. The application actions are executing as they should

Comment: Thanq very much sir... It is showing formatted error after I wrote `$this->loadComponent('Auth')`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a proper ID to the if statement to check. You have to send the logged in user's ID through the function's parameters and then check for that ID in the if statement.

Comment: even removing if statement gives error at $this->set('AUTHUSER', $this->Auth->user());

Comment: does this error occur even when the user is logged in?