# After upgrading php version All Errors Are Now "An Internal Server Error Occurred" in cake php

Tags: cakephp-3.0

i am using cake php 3. Some days ago I have updated php version from 5.6 to 7.1.17 . Now if there is any error happen in my apps it show `An Internal Server Error Occurred"`. I can see error log in my `error.log` file like this `[Error] Call to a member function user() on boolean
Request URL: /robots.txt`

Here is how my `user()` function called. It was working fine with php 5.6..

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    if($this->Auth->user()){
        $this->set('loggedIn', true);
    }
    else{
        $this->set('loggedIn',false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this happen, when you call robots.txt? Did you try to set a breakpoint and debug the beforeRender() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem. Added this line `$this->loadComponent('Auth');` in the `beforeRender` function. I got this solution from 
[Fatal error: Call to a member function user() on boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409547/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-user-on-boolean)